# How do I get HTTP error response code in Jquery POST

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-post

I have a wrapper function used to send requests to a server, I need to do something specific if the server returns a code of 401 and I'm not sure how to get this data

```
 $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();    
$.post(apiUrl+method,p,function(d) {

    $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();  
    console.log(d.success);
    console.log(d.message);

    if(d.success == true){
        window[callback](d.data);
    }
    else{
        if(d.message != null){
            alert(d.message);
        }  
    }
},'json')
.error(function() {
    //need to check for 401 status here to do something
    $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();  
    alert("error");
});
```

If my server side code throws a 401 exception the jquery .error function picks this up just because its not 200 OK but I need to check if its a 401 code.

Comment: === not ==, like wise for !== != :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the `error` callback, check `xhr.status` where `xhr` is the first argument to the function.

Answer (score 0):

Update on the "promise" method:
as of jQuery 1.5 we can call the .fail() promise and get the status code like this:

```
$.post( "example.php", function() {
    alert( "success" );
}).fail(function(xhr) {
    console.log(xhr.status);
});
```

Note that .error() promise is removed as of jQuery 3.0