# How can I get response status of a jquery POST command?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to access the return statusCode as 200/401 etc.How can I do this?

```
   var poster=$.post(url, 
    {nickname:name, email:mail},function(data) {
    alert('Inside poster done');
   });

   alert(poster.statusCode);

   poster.done(function(data){
    alert(data);
   });
```

I have tried the answer given in [How do I get HTTP error response code in Jquery POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8513295/how-do-i-get-http-error-response-code-in-jquery-post) (xhr.status), and it simply returns 0.Thought the actual response is 401 which was shown in the web console.What's the right way of accessing the return status of the POST command?

Comment: Does not work as in...? Crashes? Returns wrong value? Anything in the Javascript console?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: returns 0 on the console.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: I was working based on the last example in this documentation:http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: Why the -1?Please explain.

Answer (score 1):

although success and error call back is generated from response code but you can do it this way too. look here http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

```
$.ajax({
statusCode: {
404: function() {
alert("code 404");
}
200:function(){
alert("code 200");
}
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If by "*returned*" you mean "*in the response from the server*," you can access the value inside a callback, especially with [`.always()`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.always/) so it's called whether there's an error or not:

```
 poster.always(function(data){
   alert('status: ' + poster.status);
 });
```

Outside of those callbacks, the statement will be evaluated when the request is still pending completion. So, `poster.status` will be its default value, `0`.

---

However, if you mean you want to:

```
return poster.statusCode;
```

Then my point about the request still pending again applies. You just can't do this and get the actual value with an asynchronous request.

See [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/) for more. It focuses on the `responseText`, but `status` is set at about the same time.

Comment: The poster.always display 0 as the status.The actual status is 401.Why is that so?